# Blackberry Simulator Error 102

Tags: eclipse, blackberry, simulator

I'm having some issue launching a blackberry application with an

**"Error 102 Reload Software Invalid code in filesystem"**

popping up on the simulator. I've cleaned and deleted all the required files from all the simulators in the RIM simulator folders (run clean.bat) and in the eclipse folders. I've also cleaned it through the clean option through the eclipse environment. However even after all this I still get the error. I've been researching online and for the most part all the solutions seem to say "run clean.bat, and restart your simulator" or "delete .dmp files". This however does not work for me. I can't say whether this is due to the code since I did not code the first portion, it was left for me to continue off. I was able to run the simulator with the application showing a few times but all of a sudden it stopped (and I hadn't coded anything yet). Does anyone perhaps know any methods on how to get it to work or what is causing this?

Answer (score 0):

Deleted .dmp files on the simulator folder
Cleaned the simulator using eclipse
Cleaned the proyect

Then I run it and worked again.

Hope that this help

Answer (score 0):

Run `clean.bat` inside the simulator folder and remove any `.dmp files` also. Finally in the simulator window go to `File > Reset to Factory Defaults`. Done!